# LINQ Count returning 1 instead of zero for an empty group

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I've got this SQL query:

```
SELECT oy.ownerId, oy.Year,  COUNT(doc.Id) as docCount FROM aavabruf.owneryears oy 
left join vastdocuments doc
on oy.ownerId = doc.Ownerid and  oy.Year =  doc.Year
group by oy.ownerid, oy.year
order by docCount
```

It shows docCount as ZERO for the OwnerId, Year pairs that have no document match in the vastdocuments table.

I tried to do the same with LINQ using the suggested left outer join solution:

```
from oy in OwnerYears
join doc in VaStDocuments on new {oy.OwnerId, oy.Year} equals new {doc.OwnerId , doc.Year} into docS
from docIfNull in docS.DefaultIfEmpty()
group oy by new {oy.OwnerId, oy.Year} into g
orderby g.Count() ascending
select new { OwnerId = g.Key.OwnerId,  Year = g.Key.Year, docCount = g.Count()}
```

However, for the OwnerId, Year groups that are not present in the VastDocuments table I get docCount as ONE, not ZERO. If I remove the

> from docIfNull in docS.DefaultIfEmpty()

line the "empty" groups will not be shown at all.

How can i get the Count as zero just as it is in the SQL query? I tried the following:

> Count = docIfNull == null ? 0 : g.Count()

however in this case I get an error:

> The name 'docIfNull' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Trace the query and check it within the database itself as tsql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL `COUNT` function ignores the `NULL` values, while LINQ `Count` function w/o predicate counts everything, including `null`s.

You can get the same result in LINQ by using the predicate version of `Count` like this (note the `group docIfNull` so the `g` elements will be of the same type as `docIfNull`):

```
from oy in OwnerYears
join doc in VaStDocuments on new { oy.OwnerId, oy.Year } equals new { doc.OwnerId, doc.Year } into docS
from docIfNull in docS.DefaultIfEmpty()
group docIfNull by new { oy.OwnerId, oy.Year } into g
let docCount = g.Count(doc => doc != null)
orderby docCount ascending
select new { OwnerId = g.Key.OwnerId, Year = g.Key.Year, docCount = docCount }
```

(the `let` clause is just to reuse the expression in `orderby` and `select`).

However in LINQ you have another option - in case the `(OwnerId, Year)` combination inside `OwnerYears` is unique as it seems, instead of `left outer join` pattern followed by `group by` and `Count` filtering nulls you could use simple [group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) operator with regular `Count` call:

```
from oy in OwnerYears
join doc in VaStDocuments on new { oy.OwnerId, oy.Year } equals new { doc.OwnerId, doc.Year } into docs
let docCount = docs.Count()
orderby docCount ascending
select new { OwnerId = oy.OwnerId,  Year = oy.Year, docCount = docCount }
```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest approach is to count non-null values:

```
g.Count(x => x != null)
```

I'd suggest moving the ordering *after* the `select` so that you can avoid repeating yourself:

```
select new { g.Key.OwnerId, g.Key.Year, DocCount = g.Count(x => x != null) } into result
orderby result.DocCount
select result
```

However, I note that currently you're not *using* `docIfNull` at all at the moment... so I suspect your join isn't really doing what you want it to. Perhaps you should be using

```
group docIfNull by new { oy.OwnerId, oy.Year } into g
```

?